# deploying java webproject with websocket @ServerEndpoint in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, websocket

I wrote chat with help of java, websocket and spring mvc.

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
@RequestMapping("/")
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chating", encoders = {EncoderMessager.class}, decoders = {DecoderMessager.class})
public class ChatServerAppl {
```

When I run my code in eclipse in windows7 it works properly in tomcat7. In ubuntu 14.04.3 with the same version of tomcat I get errors like

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/Chat/chating' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

or when I edit .js file and add :8080

```
var wsUri = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/Chat/chating";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

I get another error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/Chat/chating' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

I haven't any expirience with linux and don't understand how to solve this problem. Help me pls.

Comment: I guess that I need to install something for websocket in my ubuntu =0 but don't know what and can't find the answer in google

Comment: after "implements Serializable" in class Controller everything works. Don't know why :0